# Is it really so hard to "postpone" a task (or "wait for idle")

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

How do I accomplish a "wait for idle" model with the properties:

- When a method `do()` is called, after X delay, a `close()` method will be called.
- If I call the `do()` method again **before** X time has passed, the call to `close()` must be postponed.

**EXAMPLE**

Scenario 1: (for timeout = 10 secs):

1. The user calls `do()` at time `0`.
2. At time `10`, the `close()` method is called because the user has not called `do()` again.

Scenario 2: (also timeout = 10 secs):

1. The user calls `do()` at time `0`. (so at `10` the `close()` method should be called).
2. At time of `8`, the user calls `do()` again.
3. At time of `10` nothing happens because the `close()` was postponed 10 seconds.
4. At time `18`, the `close()` method is called, because the user has not called `do()` again since `8`.

**What i have tried:**

```
private static final long delay = 10000;
private Timer t;
private TimerTask tt;

public void do() {

    ...

    // check old timer first:
    if (t != null) t.cancel();

    // create new timer
    t = new Timer();
    tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            close();
        }
    }
    // run it
    t.schedule(tt, System.currentTimeMillis() + delay);
}
private void close() {
    // do some cleanup here
}
```

This code is very ugly.
It's also very unefficient and memory-consuming, because the  `do()` function is getting called about 50 times per second.

What should I do to get this working in an efficient and neat way? (Is it really so hard?)

Comment: Why do you create the `Timer` over and over? You should reuse one timer and only cancel/schedule tasks on it. And when you fix that, there will be nothing inefficient and memory-consuming about it.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - you can't schedule tasks on a timer that has been cancelled.

Comment: @Perception Of course. That is why you **don't cancel the timer**. You cancel the task.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - never mind, I see where you stated task vs timer.

Comment: How would I reuse the timer if I cancel the task? Even if I cancel the task, can I then schedule a new task (or the same final task) in the old Timer? I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on a right way and it is not a hard one.

Here is what I want to suggest you. Create timer only once. Make it a member of class. Create its instance in constructor.

When method is called create a task as you already do now. You can however create separate class and even create it instance in advance and when `do()` method is called just schedule it, so the `close()` will be called according to your schedule.

When `do()` is called cancel the previously created close task. This will make sure that you will not close anything if method `do()` was called again.

BTW since `do` is a reserved word in java you cannot call method this way. This means that your code even cannot be compiled. Change the name.

Comment: I'm getting the idea, however I'm not fully understanding the third paragraph, what should I do in my do() method (and what in the separate class)? (And the naming was just because I wrote the code directly, hadn't thought about that).

Answer (score 1):

Set a 10 second timer task when you `open()`

Keep a variable `long lastCall` which gets set to `System.currentTimeMillis()` from `doIt()`

In the time task body, check whether `lastCall` is within 10 seconds.  If so, reschedule the timer task for the remaining time.  If not, call `close()`

Don't forget to `synchronize` on something when you read to or write from `lastCall`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a suitable solution:

```
public class TimerExample {

    private TimerTask tt;
    ScheduledFuture<?> future;
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor s;

    public TimerExample() {
        s = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                close();
            }
        };
        doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (future != null) future.cancel(true);
        future = s.schedule(tt, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("do");
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("Close");
    }

}
```